# Convert java.lang.Number using NumberAxis to DoubleAxis() with javafx and scala

Tags: scala, charts, type-conversion, javafx-2, numeric

I try to make a linechart with javafx and scala, but i have some problem converting Number to Double.

My probleme is here, `NumberAxis` extends Number (java.lang.Number)

```
val xAxis = new NumberAxis()
val yAxis = new NumberAxis()
```

You can also see api here : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html

In my program, i want to create a `new LineChart[Double,Double]` and not `LineChart[Number,Number]`, so my convert problem is here, `LineChart` cannot convert `NumberAxis` to Double.

```
//Type mistmatch
new LineChart[Double,Double](xAxis, yAxis)
```

Is there possible to define a `DoubleAxis` ? or `IntAxis` ?

Instead of that, i create all my `XYChart` with `java.lang.Number` type :

```
val xAxis = new NumberAxis()
val yAxis = new NumberAxis()

val linechart = new LineChart[Number, Number] (xAxis, yAxis)
val mySeries = new XYChart.Series[Number, Number]()

// here you can the implicit conversion between Number and Double,
// not bad, but i don't know how the conversion is made ... :/

val myData: XYChart.Data[Number, Number] = new XYChart.Data(1.0, 2.0)

mySeries.getData().add(myData)

linechart.getData().add(mySeries)
```

Do you think there is a better way to do that in scala ?

Comment: This might be an issue with scala.Double and java.lang.Double. Have you tried new LineChart[java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double]?

Comment: Don't work, no constructor for that :/ LineChart take `(Axis<X> , Axis<Y>)`, but `NumberAxis extends Axis<Number>`

Comment: I have the same exact issue here, and no alternative solution came to my mind. `Number` is an `abstract class` extended by the primitive wrappers in java. I suppose that scala makes a conversion from `scala.Double` to `java.lang.Double` under the covers, but I didn't investigate any further.

Comment: Here is the code for `NumberAxis`, so you can see what you'd need to do to create `DoubleAxis`: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/graphics/rt/file/535fa5b98147/javafx-ui-controls/src/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.java

Comment: I suppose you could pass a generic `Axis<java.lang.Double>`, with the downside that you lose some additional features supported by `NumberAxis`